# How do I implement a DataGrid with an MVVM approach

Tags: wpf, datagrid, viewmodel, mvvm

I'd like to implement a sort of Addressbook/Contactbook using a Datagrid (or a List) and the MVVM pattern.

Something like in Outlook/Thunderbird, where you've a list of your contacts displayed with a 2-3 main fields (name surname for example), and when you double-click a contact, then you get a new modal box that displays all the details of this specific contact.

Since a couple of weeks/months, I'm reading a lot of stuff about MVVM pattern on the net, but somehow, I get confused. Until now, I could find any sample like this. (perhaps, I searched wrong?)

How could I organize such an application?

**Update:**

My scenario is very similar to an application that manages Customers, Orders and Products.
The user would have as main view 3 datagrids shown through 3 tabs, one shows the list of Customers, one the Orders and one the Products.

Then in each view, you can Add, Delete (under certain conditions) an object.

Each object has a relation with another one.

For example, in a Customer instance, I've a list of Orders for that Customer and for each Order a list of Products ordered.

I'd like to implement something like this using the MVVM pattern?
Could someone help, how to structure it?
Is there a sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like [this?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Edit

I have made a simple app which does what you want, the source code can be found [here](http://cid-136dba83ff6950a3.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Code%20Samples/ContactsWithWindow.zip)

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi,
Well, yes something like this, but with an external window, not a new tab in the main view.

Comment: You could inject the viewmodel in to a the view (a window in this case) and then set the datacontext of the window to the injected VM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** useful. It shows a list of Books in a DataGrid and it shows a modal dialog to lend a book someone. The application uses the MVVM pattern.